# Coreplot in swift: change starting value of axis to 1

Tags: swift, graphics, core-plot

I have a graph and I wan't that the `x` and the 2 `y` to start at 1 not 0.

![enter image description here][1]

This is how i setup the plotspaces:

```
//plotspace 1
    var plotSpace: CPTXYPlotSpace = graph.defaultPlotSpace as CPTXYPlotSpace
    var xRange = plotSpace.xRange.mutableCopy() as CPTMutablePlotRange
    var yRange = plotSpace.yRange.mutableCopy() as CPTMutablePlotRange
    xRange.length = self.maxX
    yRange.length = maxPoids
    plotSpace.xRange = xRange
    plotSpace.yRange = yRange
//plotspace2 (second y)
    var plotSpace2: CPTXYPlotSpace = CPTXYPlotSpace()
    var xRange2 = plotSpace2.xRange.mutableCopy() as CPTMutablePlotRange
    var yRange2 = plotSpace2.yRange.mutableCopy() as CPTMutablePlotRange
    xRange2.length = self.maxX
    yRange2.length = maxEau
    plotSpace2.xRange = xRange2
    plotSpace2.yRange = yRange2
    graph.addPlotSpace(plotSpace2)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Please include relevant code

Comment: I've added more code

Comment: It's looking like the fact that it starts at 0 is somewhere in the CPTXYPlotSpace class so you'll probably have to dig around in there to find where it is set to start at 0 if it's set at all

Comment: There must be an other way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `location` of a plot range is the left end (on the x-axis) or bottom end (on the y-axis). Give each range a `location` of one (1) and adjust the `length` to the max - min (i.e., one in this case).

Comment: I have added what it does in my question